# How to set system and user-wide umask in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, umask

In previous OS X versions we used `launchd-user.conf` and `launchd.conf` to set `umask` values for our client workstations. This [does not appear to work in OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888296/set-umask-in-os-x-yosemite).

How to set system and user-wide umask in OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 8):

There is a final solution for setting system and user-wide umask in OS X Yosemite 10.10.3:

instead of user-wide `/etc/launchctl-user.conf` use:

```
launchctl config user umask 002
```

(example umask for setting 775 permissions)

instead of system-wide `/etc/launchctl.conf` use:

```
launchctl config system umask 002
```

(example umask for setting 775 permissions)

Apple published the how-to for "Yosemite umask problem" update five days ago (Apr 8, 2015) [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684).

Comment: This works!!!!!